# How to break lines at a given character if the text is forced to wrap in your textview? (android)

Tags: java, android, textview, word-wrap, accessibility

So I have my textview's height set to wrap content. It displays a sports score in the format
"CHI 99 CHA 88". I have the textview match the parent for its width. I also have the score text set to a specific textsize in "sp" units.

So on smaller phones, if there are more characters in the score, or if font size (accessibility settings) is changed, there is a chance that the text will need to wrap into 2 lines. However, I would like a way to control where (in the string) it will decide to wrap the text and make a new line. It would look best in the form
"CHI 99\nCHA 88". But I prefer the text to be on the same line unless it is forced to wrap by screen size, character count, or accessibility settings, so I don't want to hardcode in a "\n" from the beginning.

So basically, is there a way to control what character the text decides to create a new line at if there is a necessity for the text to wrap onto a new line.

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: I actually have ignored this potential problem for the moment and am working on other parts of my project as my UI isn't set in stone yet. But @sigute answer looks promising. Otherwise I might consider just making the text size small enough to where it won't ever be a problem since the "CHI 99 CHA 88" score textview will always be limited to a certain amount of characters for any score and I can make sure it will never wrap with a small enough text. But for a more robust solution, again it seems as though sigute has a potential solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of programatically calculating display sizes/characters, etc., [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) widget with two TextViews can be used control this.

An example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="5dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHI 99" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHA 88" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Normally, with default sizing, it looks like this:

[image: Layout]

If the views cannot fit horizontally, second TextView moves to the next line:

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid line breaks by use autosize and set maxLines to 1 like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:maxLines="1"  />
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have actually dabbled with autosize. Now I am not sure, but in my limited experience with autosizing text, it seems like it only works above a certain big enough text size when the accessibility settings (font size) is tweaked. Otherwise, when the font size is too small to begin with, it will not fit the textview when the accessibility settings make the font size bigger and it will cutoff the text from completely displaying in the textview. It seems like a good solution if this were not a problem with the accessibility issues

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate characters in one line according to screen width and add new line character after that.